# Make exim4 only send mail, do not make it receieve mail

Tags: email, smtp, exim

We send email locally using exim4, but we use Google Apps to receive our email. Unfortunately, exim4 is not sending mail addressed for our domain (internal notifications) to the Google Apps mail server.

Hostname of server: `server.com`

When we send an email to `something@server.com`, instead of it being sent to Google Apps as the MX records dictate, exim4 is sending this locally. We've tried changing our hostname for something else, however that results in some providers filtering our email as spam.

How can we make exim4 *not* receive email?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `server.com` from `local_domains` variable so localhost will not accept messages to the `server.com` for local delivery.